# How to fire and test a real paste event (not simulated by calling the prop) in Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to unit test a very simple feature in a React app where I'm blocking the user from pasting into a textarea by adding an `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler, like so:

```
function handlePaste(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

// ... pass it down as props

<TextareaComponent onPaste={handlePaste} />
```

The problem I'm having is that every method I've found of dispatching events in Jest or Enzyme just "simulates" the event by getting the function passed to the `onPaste` prop and calling it directly with a mock event object. That's not what I'm interested in testing.

Ideally I want to do something like this, testing that the actual value of the input hasn't changed after pasting:

```
const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent inputValue="Prefilled text" />);

const input = wrapper.find(TextareaComponent);

expect(input.value).toEqual("Prefilled text")

input.doAPaste("Pasted text")

expect(input.value).not.toEqual("Pasted text")
expect(input.value).toEqual("Prefilled text")
```

But haven't been able to find a method that works. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just testing against a synthetic event (and not some sort of secondary action -- like a pop up that warns the user that pasting is disabled), then the easiest and correct solution is to `simulate` a paste event, pass it a mocked `preventDefault` function, and then assert that the mocked function was called.

Attempting to make assertions against a real paste event is pointless as this a React/Javascript implementation (for example, making assertions that a callback function is called when an `onPaste`/`onChange` event is triggered). Instead, you'll want to test against what happens as a result of calling the callback function (in this example, making assertions that `event.preventDefault` was called -- if it wasn't called, then we know the callback function was never executed!).

**Working example** (click the `Tests` tab to run the assertions):

[image: Edit Jest with Enzyme Testing (prevent paste)]

To keep it simple, I'm just asserting that the input is initially empty and then only updates the value if an `onChange` event was triggered. This can very easily be adapted to have some sort of passed in prop influence the default input's `value`.

---

**App.js**

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    ({ target: { value } }) => setValue(value),
    []
  );

  const handlePaste = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, []);

  const resetValue = useCallback(() => {
    setValue("");
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(`Submitted value: ${value}`);
      setValue("");
    },
    [value]
  );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="foo">
        <input
          id="foo"
          type="text"
          data-testid="test-input"
          value={value}
          onPaste={handlePaste}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button data-testid="reset-button" type="button" onClick={resetValue}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { configure, mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import App from "./App";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const value = "Hello";

describe("App", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let inputNode;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
    // finding the input node by a 'data-testid'; this is not required, but easier 
    // when working with multiple form elements and can be easily removed 
    // when the app is compiled for production
    inputNode = () => wrapper.find("[data-testid='test-input']");
  });

  it("initially displays an empty input", () => {
    expect(inputNode()).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(inputNode().props().value).toEqual("");
  });

  it("updates the input's value", () => {
    inputNode().simulate("change", { target: { value } });

    expect(inputNode().props().value).toEqual(value);
  });

  it("prevents the input's value from updating from a paste event", () => {
    const mockPreventDefault = jest.fn();
    const prefilledText = "Goodbye";

    // updating input with prefilled text
    inputNode().simulate("change", { target: { value: prefilledText } });

    // simulating a paste event with a mocked preventDefault
    // the target.value isn't required, but included for illustration purposes
    inputNode().simulate("paste", {
      preventDefault: mockPreventDefault,
      target: { value }
    });

    // asserting that "event.preventDefault" was called
    expect(mockPreventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // asserting that the input's value wasn't changed
    expect(inputNode().props().value).toEqual(prefilledText);
  });

  it("resets the input's value", () => {
    inputNode().simulate("change", { target: { value } });
    wrapper.find("[data-testid='reset-button']").simulate("click");

    expect(inputNode().props().value).toEqual("");
  });

  it("submits the input's value", () => {
    inputNode().simulate("change", { target: { value } });
    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");

    expect(inputNode().props().value).toEqual("");
  });
});
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the extremely thorough example!